# Why I'm getting id is null if there exist a div with that id?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to execute a timer that when it reaches zero, the whole screen goes blank with a `document.body.innerHTML = ""`, after that, I create a `<div>` with an `<h1>` tag with a text which says "Game Over" inside a `<div>` with the id `"game____overdiv"` in the DOM. Everything goes fine except the part where I need to append the `<div>` I've created to the one in the DOM. After debugging it, it says that the result of that is null which doesn't make sense because I have the `<div>` created with the appropiate id.

```js
const timer = {
  sec: 5,
  startTimer() {
    const timeInterval = setInterval(() => {
      const minText = `${Math.floor(this.sec / 60)}`;
      const secText = `0${this.sec % 60}`.slice(-2);
      document.getElementById('gameTimer').innerHTML = `${minText}:${secText}`;
      if (this.sec <= 0) {
        clearInterval(timeInterval);
        document.getElementById('gameTimer').innerHTML = "Time's up!";
        audioHandler.gameOver();
      }

      if (this.sec <= 0) {
        document.body.innerHTML = ""
        const div = document.createElement("div")
        const text = document.createElement("h1")
        const newContent = document.createTextNode("Game Over")
        const result = document.getElementById("game____overdiv")
        div.appendChild(text)
        text.appendChild(newContent)
        result.appendChild(div)
        console.log(div)
        console.log(result)
      }

      this.sec -= 1;
      if (this.sec <= 5 && this.sec > 0) {
        audioHandler.startTimeWarning();
      } else {
        audioHandler.stopTimeWarning();
      }
    }, 1000);

  },
  timerAnswerHandling(typeOfAnswer) {
    if (typeOfAnswer === 'correct') {
      this.sec += 5;
    } else if (typeOfAnswer === 'wrong') {
      this.sec -= 5;
    }
  },
  levelupHandling() {
    this.sec += 20;
  },
};
```

Comment: you've just cleared document body ... why would there be anything with an id `game____overdiv` unless it's in the HEAD? *I have the <div> created with the appropiate id* - where? it's not created after you've emptied the body

Comment: `document.body.innerHTML` will basically destroy the whole document. What were you actually intending to do there?

Comment: You've deleted your body so there is no way `const result = document.getElementById("game____overdiv")` this exists. You will have to appendi it first to the innerHTML of your body

Comment: It would make more sense to have a specific div you can empty just for the part you actually want to make blank, then you can leave the other div in place and ready.

Comment: I think you just forgot to assign the attribute. You could simply do this with `div.setAttribute("id", "game____overdiv")`

Comment: @Sherif no that's not it. `game____overdiv` is clearly meant to be a separate existing div, because the code then goes on to try and append the new `div` element _inside_ the `game____overdiv` element.

Comment: @Bravo okay thank you now I understand the issue, but would there be a better way of clearing the whole document then?

Comment: Why would you want to clear the _whole_ document? That's rarely, if ever, necessary. Just clear the section which actually needs clearing. If something needs to stay, then leave it there. That's what we're trying to say to you. Potentially you can hide / unhide elements at different times, too, if that helps.

Comment: no - but  you don't want to do that

Comment: @Bravo I would like to clear the document so that I can render a game over text over the game without having to change routes

Comment: Perhaps, but that doesn't really mean you need to clear out the whole of `<body>`. Again, just clear the bit which actually needs clearing. If there are elements you still need, then obviously don't delete them.

Comment: Maybe you should actually just clear out the innerHTML of `game____overdiv` instead of the whole document. (That's just a guess, we can't see your HTML).